# AJAX post not able to update database

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax

How can I achieve a database insert using AJAX?

I've created a module and I'm using AJAX *post* to insert a record into the database but seem to get a silent error and no database update; I know the **`insertdata.php`** file is called as I get a syntax error recorded in my **`php_error_log`**.

1. Any idea where I when wrong with my insert?
2. Is there any way to show error log or console log in the **`insertdata.php`** file?

   ***`error_log('My Error: ', 0);`*** doesn't seem to work.

Below is the content of my **default.php**:

```
<div id="update_dialog" title="Update Details" style = "display:none">
    <form method="post" id="my_form" action="modules/mod_myPage/insertdata.php">
        <label>Company Name :</label><input id="Company_Name" type="text"></input>
        <label>Company Address :</label><input id="Company_Address" type="text"></input>
        <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#submit").click(function () {

        _Company_Name = jQuery("#Company_Name").val();
        _Company_Address = jQuery("#Company_Address").val();

        jQuery.post("modules/mod_myPage/insertdata.php",
            {
                Company_Name: _Company_Name,
                Company_Address: _Company_Address
            },
            function (data, status) {
                alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
            });
    });
});
</script>
```

And that of my **insertdata.php** file:

```
<?php
defined ( '_JEXEC' ) or die ();


if( isset( $_POST['Company_Name'] ) )
    {
        $_Company_Name = $_POST['Company_Name'];
        $_Company_Address = $_POST['Company_Address'];

        $insert_query = "INSERT INTO #__myCompany (Company_Name, Company_Address, Create_Date)
        VALUES('".$_Company_Name."','".$_Company_Address."','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')";

        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        try
        {
            $db->setQuery($insert_query);
            $db->query();
        }
        catch (RuntimeException $e)
        {
            $e->getMessage();
            error_log('This query failed: '.$insert_query, 0);
            error_log($e->getMessage(), 0);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

After more searches, I managed to work it out.  Hopefully the below will offer some small mercy to some lost joomla soul like I was. The main challenge was constructing the URL and get a response. So here's my solution

url: "index.php?option=com_ajax&module=CompanyPage&method=updateDetails&format=raw"

1. Required if using ajax request: **index.php?option=com_ajax**
2. Your module being `mod_CompanyPage` is called without the *mod_* as : **&module=CompanyPage**
3. Your method in the helper class must have the key word *Ajax* at the end of the function. `function updateDetailsAjax()` but is constructed without the word Ajaxas : **&method=updateDetails**
4. Finally the **&format=raw** at the end. (I haven't work out why yet)

To get a response from the helper class just echo it out.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#submit").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "index.php?option=com_ajax&module=CompanyPage&method=updateDetails&format=raw",
       data: dataString,
       success: function(data){
       alert(data);    // alert box pop up either show "We did it" or the error message from data connection
       }
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

helper.php

```
class modCompanyPageHelper
{

    function updateDetailsAjax()
    {  

        if( isset( $_POST['Company_Name'] ) )
        {

            $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

            $_Company_Name = $jinput->get('Company_Name', 'default_value', 'RAW');
            $_Company_Address = $jinput->get('Company_Address', 'default_value', 'RAW');

            $insert_query = "INSERT INTO #__myCompany (Company_Name, Company_Address, Create_Date)
            VALUES('".$_Company_Name."','".$_Company_Address."','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')";

            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);

            try
            {
                $db->setQuery($insert_query);
                $db->query();
            }
            catch (RuntimeException $e)
            {

                echo $e->getMessage();
                return false;
            }
            echo "We did it";
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

With this knowledge, I was able to call backend function to insert, upload and delete database record.  I also managed to upload files on to server using dropzone.js

Life would have been so much easier had I known this info a month ago.

Comment: I managed to get a response from the helper class.  Just echo back.

Answer (score 1):

Please, use Joomla's Ajax interface which is fully explained [here](http://www.itoctopus.com/how-to-use-joomlas-ajax-interface-component-com_ajax). Do not reinvent the wheel and use your own Ajax calls - this is bad both for security and scalability.